# What's the meaning of "Let me worry about it"?

Tags: meaning

I've come across the phrase below and I don't understand it's meaning:

> Let me worry about the fees.

So, Coud you please explain it to me?

The main text is here:

> At my next supervision, Professor Steinberg said that when I applied for
>   graduate school, he would make sure I was accepted to whatever
>   institution I chose. “Have you visited Harvard?” he said. “Or perhaps you
>   prefer Cambridge?”
>     [...] “I can’t go,” I said. “I can’t pay the fees.”
>   “Let me worry about the fees,” Professor Steinberg said.

*Educated* by Tara Westover

Comment: It means "don't think about the cost, I will pay, but *how* I will pay need not be your concern." The word "worry" could mean that the speaker might have difficulty paying, but will find a way. That is not the student's concern, who certainly cannot pay the fees.

Comment: It's a euphemism for:  I will take care of  the money issues.

Comment: @WeatherVane - What you said is true, but I believe this expression is typically used when the speaker **won't** have any trouble paying. It's just a polite reply that essentially means, "Don't worry; I'll pay."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The narrator is worried that she won't be able to afford the cost of a post-graduate degree. Professor Steinberg is offering to pay her fees or otherwise fund her education. He means "You don't need to worry about the fees. I will sort that out."

Either the professor will pay her fees, or he will use his influence and connections to find a sponsor or a grant.